# Training Code Not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I am going through the book "ActionScript 3.0 Animation ~ Making Things Move" by Keith Peters, and one of the examples is teaching Parent Boxs... I have written this code out, and upon execution, it runs, but provides no Errors, nothing happens, none of the Sprites are drawn, its a blank canvas..? Using Flash Pro CS 6, 12.0.2.529. I haven't had issues with any other examples as of yet, and the .as "ParentBox" runs fine, when I try to run ParentBox2 is when I am encountering this issue.... Thoughts? (sorry, pretty new to OOP, trying to learn as much as I can, and this website in particular has ben AMAZING so far for the vast wealth of knowledge....

ParentBox.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class ParentBox extends Sprite {
        public function ParentBox()
        {
            init();
        }
        private function init():void{
            graphics.lineStyle(1, 0);
            graphics.drawRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);

        }
    }}
```

ParentBox2.as Code....

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class ParentBox2 extends Sprite {
        private var parent1:ParentBox;
        private var parent2:ParentBox;
        private var ball:Sprite;

    public function Reparenting2 (){
        init();
    }
    private function init():void{
        parent1 = new ParentBox();
        addChild(parent1);
        parent1.x = 60;
        parent1.y = 60;

        parent2 = new ParentBox();
        addChild(parent2);
        parent2.x = 170;
        parent2.y = 60;

        ball = new Sprite();
        parent1.addChild(ball);
        ball.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
        ball.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 40);
        ball.graphics.endFill();
        ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBallClick);
    }
    public function onBallClick(event:MouseEvent):void{     
        parent2.addChild(ball);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
public class ParentBox2 extends Sprite {
```

needed to be renamed to

```
public class Reparenting2 extends Sprite {
```

for the function... Like I said, I'm still learning, especially the naming stuffs, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You have already found the answer, but for any one else having the same problem,

In ActionScript3 the constructor function should have the same name as the class name.

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class ParentBox2 extends Sprite {
    private var parent1:ParentBox;
    private var parent2:ParentBox;
    private var ball:Sprite;

public function ParentBox2 (){ //the constructor function's name should be the same as that of the class.
    init();
}
...
```